# How to change bootstrap typographic measurement in the appropriate way?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-size, typography

Currently Bootstrap 3 used `html {font-size: 62.5%;}` and then

```
body {

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;

}
```

and than px everywhere for typography

```
h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5,
.h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
h6,
.h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

And in current condition if I want to make default `font-size` to `16px` should I also increase the `px` size of all heading levels like `36` to `38` for `h1` and also change the `line-height` which is `1.42857143` for `14px` `font-size`

**Or** I can just change `html {font-size: 62.5%;}` to something else and no editing required for `body`, **heading** and **line height**

Comment: `rem`, `rem`,  `rem` (but not remy sharp!) I use `rem`. Zurb foundation uses `rem`. Everybody should use `rem` :)

Comment: `rem` is not supported in IE8 & below, so be forewarned.

Answer (score 2):

Just trying a quick test seems to reveal the answer:

[**Example with: `html {font-size: 62.5%;}`**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/j3B3H/)
[**Example with: `html {font-size: 100%;}`**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/j3B3H/3/)

The two examples look exactly the same because font sizes set in non-relative units, like `px`, will not be effected by changes to a parent element's font-size.

If you would like to have this kind of functionality try using `em`, like so:

**[Example with `body{font-size: 62.5%;}`](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/j3B3H/6/)**
**[Example with `body{font-size: 100%;}`](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/j3B3H/7/)**

CSS using em units:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 3.6em; /* equal to 36px */
}
h2, .h2 {
    font-size: 3.0em; /* equal to 30px */
}
h3, .h3 {
    font-size: 2.4em; /* equal to 24px */
}
h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.8em; /* equal to 18px */
}
h5, .h5 {
    font-size: 1.4em; /* equal to 14px */
}
h6, .h6 {
    font-size: 1.2em; /* equal to 12px */
}
```

Credible Source:

> The most popular method in working with em values is to set the
>   font-size on the body to 62.5%. Because the default browser font-size
>   is 16px, this makes it 10px (without hard-setting it to 10px, which
>   wouldn't cascade). Using 10 as a multiplier is much easier than using
>   16. This way, you need a font size of 18px? Use font-size: 1.8em.
>
> So why both with all this em business when it's just an abstraction of
>   using pixel values anyway? Three possible reasons:
>
> 1. They ARE resizable in IE 6
> 2. The relationship to other sizes (elastic width sites)
> 3. Em's cascade like a mo-fo

Excerpt from:
[px – em – % – pt – keyword

Published April 16, 2009 by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)

I'm guessing this method may be the origin of the `html{font-size: 62.5%;}` found in your code.

Comment: Thanks. How to control line-height in proportion with font-weight?

Comment: @JitendraVyas It shouldn't be an issue if you're using a unit-less value for the line height, for example 1 not 1em or 20px

Comment: @JitendraVyas See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height "The used value is this unitless <number> multiplied by the element's font size. The computed value is the same as the specified <number>. In most cases this is the preferred way to set line-height with no unexpected results in case of inheritance."

Comment: You may also find useful the PX to EM calculator: http://pxtoem.com/.  Use EM or percents (not px) if you want to support IE's 'View:Text-size' option in browser.  So to get 16px base, you can use body 100% and do nothing else.  But if you want to be more IE-responsive, you change all the px font sizes using the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#typography) to do this with ease. You'll need to manually adjust the line height, but the font sizes for h1..6 are generated based on `@font-size-base`.

Comment: But I'm using  Sass version

Comment: Would have been useful to know that from the start. Anyway, if you use the official Sass version you just need to override the `$font-size-base` variable.

Comment: I did that but just changing the `$font-size-base` doesn work well with input labels, and my question if we change `$font-size-base` how to edit `line-height`

Comment: To change the `line-height` you need to edit the [`$line-height-base`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L64) variable.

Comment: I mean I wanted to know how to change font size and line height in proportion. if you read my question again you will understand. my question is not about where to edit properties. I want to know the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way that you can control the typography in Bootstrap responsive design is by using @Media Queries. You have 4 break points in Bootstrap lg, md, sm and xs, so just choose 1 font size for each resolution group.